# Can I use transparent routes for sub apps?

Tags: node.js, express

Express requires the sub app to have an absolute route defined.
I can't just use `'/'` in `otherApp` to match all the stuff `app` routes to it.

```
var app = express();
var otherApp = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('HELLO!');
});

//this works
otherApp.get('/other', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.path);
});

//this doesn't
otherApp.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.path);
});

app.get('/other*', otherApp);
```

If I want to change the route to otherApp, I'd have to change it in the sub-app too.

**Is there any way to define this transparently/relative for all the sub-apps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `app.use('/other/', otherApp);`. Notice it's `use` and not `get`.